# Epsilon Greedy Performing better than UCB for small number of arms

Tags: c++, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am implementing the bandit problem using various algorithms. The issue that I am facing is that epsilon-greedy is performing better than UCB for 5arms and horizon of 2000 for an epsilon value of 0.95.
I am aware of the fact that epsilon-greedy does indeed perform better when the horizon is comparable with a number of arms.
But since my arms are significantly less than the horizon, UCB should perform better. Any idea why this is happening?
I am enclosing my UCB implementation.

```
else if(algorithm.compare("UCB") == 0){

if(pulls == 0){
  armpullfrequency = new int[numArms];
  armRewards = new float[numArms];
  armmean = new double[numArms];
  UCB = new double[numArms];

  for(int i=0; i<numArms; i++){
    armpullfrequency[i] = 0;
    armRewards[i] = 0.0;
    armmean[i] = (double)0;
    UCB[i] = (double)0;
  }
}

else{

  armpullfrequency[pulled_arm] = armpullfrequency[pulled_arm] + 1;
  armRewards[pulled_arm] = armRewards[pulled_arm] + reward;
}
int selected_arm = 0;
//int randint = (rand() % 100);
if(pulls<=6){
  for(int i=0;i<numArms;i++){
    if(armpullfrequency[i]==0){
      selected_arm = i;
      return selected_arm;
    }
  }
}

for(int i=0;i<numArms;i++){
    int freq = armpullfrequency[i];
    float prize = armRewards[i];
    double mean = eval_mean(freq, prize);
    armmean[i] = mean;
  }

for(int i=0; i<numArms;i++){
  int freq = armpullfrequency[i];
  double mean = armmean[i];
  double UCBval = UCBUpdate(mean, freq, pulls);
  UCB[i] = UCBval;
}

selected_arm = LargestElementIndex(UCB, numArms);
return(selected_arm);
```

My UCB and LargestElementIndex function are:-

```
int LargestElementIndex(double arr[], int size){
  int max = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<size; i++){
    if(arr[i]>max){
     max = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}

int UCBUpdate(double mean, int freq, int pulls){
  double result = mean + sqrt((double)2.0 *(log(pulls))/(double)freq);
  return result;
}
```

The results in case of UCB is:-
maxMean 0.5805 numTotalPulls 2000 cumulativeReward 716.308
Regret = 444.692

The results in the case of Epsilon Greedy is:-
max means 0.5805 numTotalPulls 2000 cumulativeReward 823.948
Regret = 337.052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the error is in the following code:

```
int LargestElementIndex(double arr[], int size){
  int max = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<size; i++){
    if(arr[i]>max){
     max = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return max;
}
```

This does not return the index of the arm with the greatest UCB value (which is probably what you intended). This code simply returns the greatest UCB value in the array itself, after casting it to an `int`. This can likely be fixed as follows:

```
int LargestElementIndex(double arr[], int size){
  double max_val = -1000.0;
  int max_idx = -1;
  for(int i=0;i<size; i++){
    if(arr[i]>max_val){
     max_val = arr[i];
     max_idx = i;
    }
  }
  return max_idx;
}
```